# Crystal Report Sub-Header Repeat

Tags: crystal-reports, grouping, crystal-reports-2008, sections

I am working with Crystal Reports, At the moment, I have a sub-report which is further divided into Groups , For each Group I am showing the Headers Separately,

The issue is , when a group's details reaches at the bottom of the page and next Group Header-Sub-Header appears on the same page , but their details section goes on to next page with no header's , that is ambiguous, or non- readable. below i am attaching the Screen Shots.

For for Top Header and One for Sub-Group Header

**"I want that Sub-Group repeats on every new page"**

[image: Top Header]

Here the Sub-Group
[image: Sub-Header]

Can any body Suggest a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I did with , this option.

Go to Group Expart, click on 'options' button. Select the 'options' tab and check 'Repeat group header on each page'